# Setting text of JLabel within paint(g)- is this wrong?

Tags: java, applet

Snippet of code is here:

```
        int area;
        int[] xcoords = new int[3];
        xcoords[0] = coordsAX;
        xcoords[1] = coordsBX;
        xcoords[2] = coordsCX;
        sortArray(xcoords);
        int[] ycoords = new int[3];
        ycoords[0] = coordsAY;
        ycoords[1] = coordsBY;
        ycoords[2] = coordsCY;
        sortArray(ycoords);
        //Remember, array[0] is the biggest and array[2] is the smallest!
        int rectWidth = xcoords[0] - xcoords[2];
        int rectHeight = ycoords[0] - ycoords[2];

        area = (rectWidth * rectHeight);
        System.out.println(area);
        lblArea.setText("Area: " + area);
```

The entirety of the code is within the paint(g) method of my applet. I'm aiming to let the user be able to see the JLabel. Calculations go absolutely fine. But when I run, the applet looks like:

[image]

I've gathered that the setText line should not be in paint(g) but, in that case, where should it go in order to make it so the JLabel remains the same until a new triangle is generated (by clicking "Click Me" button)?

Please note that I'm a high schooler teaching myself Java and, as a result, my knowledge of the language looks like a hunk of Swiss Cheese. I'd appreciate explanations that don't explain too many topics that are well above the level of basic applet making. :)

Appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: 1) I'd say this is a strong case for not mixing together custom painting and the controls.  This is further supported by the triangle overwriting part of the text field.  Instead put those components in a panel at the `PAGE_START` of a `BorderLayout` that has the rendering in a separate panel in the `CENTER`.  2) That looks like AWT.  This millennium, use Swing (in which that top panel might be a `JToolBar`).  3) Code frames before applets, then code hybrid frame-applets when more experienced.  Applets are harder to develop.  4) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you have an action listener attached to the "click me" button.

When the action is fired, I would update the label and the UI at that point.

You might like to have a read through [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

(I'm also kind of worried that it looks like you're using AWT instead of Swing, but I could be mistaken ;))

**UPDATED example**

[image]

```
public class TestArea {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestArea();
    }

    public TestArea() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new AreaPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class AreaPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel areaLabel;

        public AreaPane() {
            areaLabel = new JLabel("Area: ...");
            JButton clickMe = new JButton("Click Me");
            clickMe.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    areaLabel.setText("Area: " + NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(Math.random() * 1000));
                    // update UI as required
                }

            });

            add(areaLabel);
            add(clickMe);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"looks like you're using AWT instead of Swing"*  What smell like?  *"Huh?"*  **Smell,** what **smell** like?  (..with apologies to Cheech'n'Chong).  Yes, looks (and smells) like AWT here too.